# Union of possible combinations of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame looks like this:

> ```
> A    B
> 100  1
> 100  2
> 200  2
> 200  3
> ```

I need to find all possible combinations of A and B values and create new dataframe with this combinations and a third column indicating each combination presence in the original df:

> ```
> A   B  C
> 100 1  True
> 100 2  True
> 100 3  False
> 200 1  False
> 200 2  True
> 200 3  True
> ```

How I'm doing it now:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [100,100,200,200], 'B' : [1,2,2,3]})
df['D'] = 42
df2 = df[['A','D']].merge(df[['B','D']], on = 'D')
  [['A','B']].drop_duplicates()
i1 = df.set_index(['A','B']).index
i2 = df2.set_index(['A','B']).index
df2['C'] = i2.isin(i1)
print(df2)
```

It works, but looks ugly. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

- create new column filled `True`s
- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from columns for all combinations
- create [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) from levels of `df1` index
- [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) original `df` and if not exist values add `False`s
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`

---

```
df['C'] = True
df1 = df.set_index(['A','B'])
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels, names=df1.index.names)
df = df1.reindex(mux, fill_value=False).reset_index()
print (df)
     A  B      C
0  100  1   True
1  100  2   True
2  100  3  False
3  200  1  False
4  200  2   True
5  200  3   True
```

Comment: Can be reduced to `mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels, names=df1.index.names)`?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `itertools` and `tuple`

```
import itertools

newdf = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df['A'].unique(),df['B'].unique())),columns = df.columns)

dft = list(df.itertuples(index=False))
newdf['C'] = newdf.apply(lambda x: tuple(x) in dft,axis=1)
```

Output :

```
     A  B   C
0  100  1   True
1  100  2   True
2  100  3  False
3  200  1  False
4  200  2   True
5  200  3   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cartesian_product` and `pd.merge`

```
In [415]: combs = pd.core.reshape.util.cartesian_product(
                  df.set_index(['A', 'B']).index.levels)

In [416]: combs
Out[416]:
[array([100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)]

In [417]: (pd.DataFrame({'A': combs[0], 'B': combs[1]})
             .merge(df, how='left', indicator='C')
             .replace({'C': {'both': True, 'left_only': False}}) )
Out[417]:
     A  B      C
0  100  1   True
1  100  2   True
2  100  3  False
3  200  1  False
4  200  2   True
5  200  3   True
```

For combs, you could also,

```
In [432]: pd.core.reshape.util.cartesian_product([df.A.unique(), df.B.unique()])
Out[432]:
[array([100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)]
```